# proxy_command で中継する踏み台サーバーで、中継されたとき走らせたいスクリプトがある

Tags: openssh

踏み台を経由して、 VPC にアクセスする場合を考えます。

たとえば、何かしら ssh の接続があった場合に、 slack に投稿するであったりのような制御をかけたいと思いました。

とくに、踏み台を経由する際に、 ProxyCommand で直接踏み台自体には login しない場合でも、この処理をどうにか走らせたいと思っています。

#### 質問

- ssh を受け入れる側の設定で、すべての ssh 接続(含む ProxyCommand で経由されている場合)に対して、実行されるような、フックのスクリプトを記述ことは可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

試してませんが SSH login の hook は PAM でできると思います。

`/etc/sshd_config` で `UserPAM` を `yes` に設定して restart
`/etc/pam.d/sshd` ファイルに次の行を追加

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /path/to/your/hook.sh
```

※確認する場合は、接続中の ssh セッションを切らずに、別窓で 接続テストするのが良いです。